# VS2015 - Dropdown Options in Javascript Console Dissappear

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2015, console

Usually when I output an object to the javascript console in VS2015, there will be an arrow next to it allowing you to expand and further inspect the element.

Running the debug console today I noticed these arrows were gone.

Does anyone know how to get these back?

Thanks for your help!

[image: this is what my output looks like, should be an arrow on the left side]

Comment: Can you share us a screen shot about the result in your side? Do you create the JavaScript Windows 8.1 app or others? If you use the same sample as this one provided by Daniel Aranda here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484838/console-logarray-shows-different-array-contents-than-iterating-the-array-and-d, what result did you get in the JavaScript Console window in VS2015? I could get the [object Array] with a dropdown list in my JavaScript Console window using the latest VS2015 with IE 11 with a simple JavaScript Windows 8.1 App.

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem. Here is my post from yesterday, no real answer yet but you might be interested:

[Visual studio 2015: can't see objects content in javascript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294540/visual-studio-2015-cant-see-objects-content-in-javascript-console)

I've got this problem for a week.

Comment: It's so odd, at first I thought I just hit a key or something to disable it, but it must be a bug or something.

Comment: I don't know... I'm losing so much time on my project :/